# Smoother and faster rotation on ProgressDialog

Tags: android

I have a custom animation to my ProgressDialog which is set this way:

```
pd.setIndeterminateDrawable(c.getResources().getDrawable(R.anim.progress_animation));
```

The `progress_animation` is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toDegrees="358" >

    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="8"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <size
            android:height="48dip"
            android:width="48dip" />

        <gradient
            android:centerColor="#4c737373"
            android:centerY="0.50"
            android:endColor="#E66A0F"
            android:startColor="#4c737373"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>

</animated-rotate>
```

This will give me an orange spinning wheel, but this seems to be "slower" or more laggy than the default spinning wheel in the ProgressDialog. I've tried setting the `android:toDegrees` from 360 to 358, but with no luck. I have also enabled hardware acceleration. Is there anyway I can make this animation smoother, or faster?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use "rotate" instead of "animated-rotate" and change android:toDegrees should make it go faster.

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="2160" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

Create my_progress_indeterminate.xml at drawable(created).
The load_spool.png is the Image to rotate.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:drawable="@drawable/load_spool"
     android:pivotX="50%"
     android:pivotY="50%"
     android:fromDegrees="0"
     android:toDegrees="2160">
  </rotate>
```

The Layout:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/my_progress_indeterminate" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try android:toDegrees="1080"  i my case it works .... just try this

Comment: doesnt make any changes in the rotation speed nor the laggyness. Thanks for your contribution.